# How to handle response of more than 4000 characters using camunda external task

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

When using external task feature provided by camunda I am facing issue if response is more that 4k characters. I am using this module to implement external task feature

https://www.npmjs.com/package/camunda-external-task-client-js

**Exception:-**

```
   NULL,
      3,
      NULL,
      NULL
    ) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: **ERROR: value too long for type character varying(4000)**
'. Flush summary:
 [
  INSERT HistoricVariableInstanceEntity[dd43fad7-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT HistoricJobLogEventEntity[dd4421ea-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT HistoricVariableUpdateEventEntity[dd3be481-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT HistoricVariableUpdateEventEntity[dd3c32a4-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT HistoricVariableUpdateEventEntity[dd43fad8-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT HistoricExternalTaskLogEntity[dd3ccee6-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT ByteArrayEntity[dd3c32a2-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT ByteArrayEntity[dd3c32a3-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT ByteArrayEntity[dd3ca7d5-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT VariableInstanceEntity[dd43fad7-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  INSERT MessageEntity[dd4421e9-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  DELETE ExternalTaskEntity[cadab10c-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  UPDATE VariableInstanceEntity[c82b4842-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  UPDATE VariableInstanceEntity[c82b4845-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[cad273a0-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[cad273a2-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
  DELETE VariableInstanceEntity[cad273a4-904e-11ea-bb50-0242ac1f030a]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the Camunda variables limit of 4000 chars. Your instance process in Camunda has to serve the response in any format but not as a String to sort it out. A couple of suggestions:

1. Wrap the response into an object (not a String). This way it is saved in the database as a blob.
2. Use Camunda Spin and process it as JSON https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/reference/spin/